# suppress cron emails from cleaning systemlog if 0B were cleaned

Tags: cron, journalctl

When cron runs

```
0 16   *   *   *     journalctl --vacuum-time=10d
```

I get an email with the content like

```
Vacuuming done, freed 0B of archived journals from /var/log/journal.
Vacuuming done, freed 0B of archived journals from /var/log/journal/68eb3115209f4deb876284bab504772b.
Vacuuming done, freed 0B of archived journals from /run/log/journal.
```

sometimes there is some bytes freed, but how do I suppress those emails if there were 0B freed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplest thing to do is to pipe through `2>&1 | grep -v 'freed 0B'`

If cron runs a command that produces zero lines of output, then cron will not send an email.

Comment: works like a charm: `0 16   *   *   *     journalctl --vacuum-time=10d 2>&1 | grep -v 'freed 0B'`